# Pretty URLS for ErrorDocument, Need advice with my rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> My Goal

When someone visits my page and some error happens, no matter the code, they see a url similar to this

```
https://example.com/403
```

> My Rewrite rules for accomplishing this

```
RewriteRule ^([4|5][0-9][0-9])$ /error.php?errorcode=$1 [L,R]
ErrorDocument 403 /403
```

> Whats happening

So when i visit say, **https://example.com/.htaccess**, i would expect it to go to **https://example.com/403** but instead it goes to **https://example.com/error.php?errorcode=403**

Can anyone offer me any guidance in what i need to do to accomplish what i want it to look like?  Not only do i want to fix this but i'd like to learn what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^([4|5][0-9][0-9])$ /error.php?errorcode=$1 [L]
```

Without `[R]`

But I do not understand your reasons, because normally the URL does not change with this kind of error...

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work. :/  When I remove [R] it doesn't responde the the error codes properly and the url above doesn't change to the proper error code.  [My website with 403 properly displayed](https://agentc0re.com/error.php?errorcode=403) AND  [This is how my website looks without the 'R'](https://agentc0re.com/.htaccess) And what i wish is for it to look like the first link but have the URL display like https://example.com/403 <--could be any code.

Comment: responde == display.. what a weird typo.

Comment: Just found out something [very interesting happening](https://agentc0re.com/.htaccess?errorcode=403)  Notice how I added the ?errorcode=403 to the end of .htaccess when trying to access it.  It actually displays the error message on screen properly.  Weird.